# Plot time series with PGFPlots and GNUPlot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, dateplot

I am trying to plot a large time series using PGFPlots, but it takes ages and often crashes with memory error, so I thought to use GNUPlot. This works fine with the same data but with simple sequential x coordinates, but when using datetimes PGFPlots can't parse GNUPlot's output.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{filecontents}{values.csv}
datetime,value
2016-01-01 00:00:00,1
2016-01-02 00:00:00,6
2016-01-05 00:00:00,3
2016-01-08 00:02:00,6
2016-01-13 00:00:00,9
2016-01-25 03:05:00,3
2016-02-05 03:04:00,7
2016-05-31 00:00:00,9
2016-12-01 12:04:00,4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    date ZERO=2016-01-01,
    ]
\addplot gnuplot [id=my_datetime_plot, raw gnuplot] {
    set xdata time;
    set timefmt "\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S";
    set format x "\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S";
    set datafile separator ",";
    plot "values.csv" using 1:2 w lines;
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After I run latex on it, the file `paper.my_datetime.table` is correctly populated by GNUPlot:

```
# Curve 0 of 1, 9 points
# Curve title: ""values.csv" using 1:2"
# x y type
"2016-01-01 00:00:00" 1.0000000e+00  i
"2016-01-02 00:00:00" 6.0000000e+00  i
"2016-01-05 00:00:00" 3.0000000e+00  i
"2016-01-08 00:02:00" 6.0000000e+00  i
"2016-01-13 00:00:00" 9.0000000e+00  i
"2016-01-25 03:05:00" 3.0000000e+00  i
"2016-02-05 03:04:00" 7.0000000e+00  i
"2016-05-31 00:00:00" 9.0000000e+00  i
"2016-12-01 12:04:00" 4.0000000e+00  i
```

However, now PGFPlots can't seem to parse the dates:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '00:00:00"' as a floating point
 number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ':00:00"'..
```

I guess it considers the line

```
"2016-01-01 00:00:00" 1.0000000e+00  i
```

as four different fields, ignoring the quotes.

I thought one quick fix would be to tell GNUPlot to export the datetime without spaces, e.g.

```
set format x "\%Y-\%m-\%dT\%H:\%M:\%S";
```

but now PGFPlots won't parse them. As far as I can tell, PGFPlots datetime format is hardcoded to

```
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Am I missing something? How can I specify the datetime format?

I saw [this unsolved question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140864/datetime-plot-in-pgfplot-using-gnuplot). In my case I can make GNUPlot output correct values, the problem seems to be within PGFPlots.

Comment: Sorry, but why do you think PGFPlots will not "crash" when you just want to plot the **same** data, i.e. without manipulating the number of points or whatever, but just using `raw gnuplot`, which will also just plot a table ...

Comment: And the `gnuplot` output is *not* correct, because there shouldn't be any quotation marks around the date-time block, but another column separator as the space, because this is already used as a separator between the date and the time.

Comment: Plotting with PGFPlots directly gives an out or memory error with pdflatex and just does not end with lualatex (I waited about 1 hour). I saw advices to use GNUPlot in these cases, and plotting by row index does indeed work in under 1 minute. Your comment makes sense, but then why does this happen?

I'm not familiar with GNUPlot's output format (I found very little documentation about `set table`), but I assumed space inside quotes wouldn't count as separator, as same with commas in CSV files.

Comment: I am as well not familiar with gnuplot, so unfortunately I cannot help you there. But it sounds weird that plotting against the row index works fine but against the date does not. Could you provide the full data file so I can try myself?